# Usually after Windows updates the device name of my hard drives change

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

So every now and then, not on *every* Windows update, but notably connected with Windows updates, the device names of some of my hard drives change.

For example just today after running a Windows update, the two hard drives seen in the object manager namespace as `\Device\Harddisk0` and `\Device\Harddisk1` switched places. Correspondingly the volume device name changed from `\Device\Harddisk1\Partition7` to `\Device\Harddisk0\Partition7`.

For the most part this wouldn't be an issue because the way drive letters get assigned doesn't rely on these device names.

However, I need to rely on the device name to mount encrypted volumes.

How can I teach Windows 7 to always assign the same device name to a given hard drive?

---

From the perspective of a driver writer I don't see one as these things are sorted out in a PnP fashion, but maybe there is something in userland that allows for it based on some device ID similar to the way USBDLM handles things at the volume level?

Comment: btw, why have you deleted your other question? is the issue fixed? "The update is not applicable to your computer" means a requirement is missing or you already have a newer version installed.